# place of ''in stock '' in different places

Tags: meaning

> 1) The amount of products is 4500 kg in reel stock.But according to computer there are 5000 kg.
>
> 2) The amount of products in stock is 4500 kg.But according to computer there are 5000 kg.

Which sentence is correct ? In these sentence I used ''in'' in different places . I think there is no different but second one sounds more natural ? Are there any difference ?

Comment: "reel" stock or did you mean "real" stock ?

Comment: The first sentence means that you have 4500kg of reels. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the sound of either. I would say:

> There is 4500g of product in stock.

The noun "product" can be countable or uncountable - in other words, you can use it in singular form to describe *all* your different types of product.